# Issue with sending web requests

Tags: c#, http, networking

I have developed a Windows service that will, among other things, use the HttpClient to query various web sites on our web server.  Since the service is running under the NETWORK SERVICE account, some sites return a 500 error even though they are up.  I tried doing this in a web app, but it requires the web app to be up at all times and the app pool account is also throwing the same error.

The only workaround I've found is to plug in a NetworkCredential with my user name, password and domain.  Obviously that's not a real solution because of security concerns and I'd have to update the app everytime my password changed.  But at least all of the apps return 200 that are supposed to.

We have a database that handles the access to the sites based on the windows logon.  The database only takes valid Employees.  NETWORK SERVICE isn't an employee.  Perhaps I need to allow Anonymous access on these sites at the virtual directory level.  NETWORK SERVICE will use anonymous privileges when accessing these sites.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is the 500 error you are getting? Those kinds of details need to go in your question.

Comment: InternalServerError

Comment: That's the error returned to the client and all it means is that something went wrong *on the server*. You need to go to the server, and find out what the error means. Often that gets logged to the Windows event log. You should be able to launch Event Viewer and look in the Applications folder and see some related errors. Or otherwise check whatever logging framework those apps have in place (or put a proper logging framework in place, using tools like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) or [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/)).

Comment: I added more content to my question.  I am using NLog and these sites will throw InternalServerError, but most of the sites are fine.  I navigated to these sites myself and everything was fine.

Comment: That still does not change the fact that you need to find out exactly what the Internal Server Error is. Otherwise you're guessing in the dark at why they're giving you a 500. And that's a big waste of your time. You say you've got NLog: then check the logs and see what the errors are. And if there aren't errors in there, then add additional logging to your application.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by removing the using statement around the HttpResponseMessage object.  Below is the code that's now working.

```
 public override async Task<bool> QueryWebSites()
    {
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();            
        clientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        clientHandler.PreAuthenticate = true;

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler)) {
            foreach (CRITICAL_APPS app in this.apps) {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(app.URL);                        
                    bool success = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    if (!success) {
                        LOGGER.Debug(app.URL + " failed" + response.StatusCode);
                        LOGGER.Debug(response.ReasonPhrase);
                        LOGGER.Debug(response.RequestMessage);
                        appStatus.Add(new CRITICAL_APPS_STATUS {APP_ID = app.ID, INITIAL_DETECTION =DateTime.Now, ID = 77 });
                    } else {
                        LOGGER.Debug(app.URL + " succeeded");
                    }                   
            }
        }
        clientHandler.Dispose();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I ran the exact code again and I got the same error messages as before.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by putting a custom error page in the app if the user did not have access to the site.

WHOEVER GAVE THIS QUESTION A -1 SHOULD TAKE IT OFF.  THIS MAY HELP OTHERS WHO HAVE HAD A SIMILAR ISSUE.

The code below allowed me to trace the issue.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler)) {                
            foreach (CRITICAL_APPS app in this.apps) {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(app.URL))
                {
                    bool success = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    if (success) {
                        LOGGER.Debug(app.URL + " succeeded");
                    } else {
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                        {                               
                            // Try to read response, log error etc.
                            var errorxml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            LOGGER.Debug(app.URL + " failed" + errorxml);                                
                        }
                        appStatus.Add(new CRITICAL_APPS_STATUS { APP_ID = app.ID, INITIAL_DETECTION = DateTime.Now, ID = 77 });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        clientHandler.Dispose();
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a windows domain account with minimal permissions, and then either run the webservice as that user (preferred) or embed the credentials for that account in its config file and have it set during the deployment process.